# swift: is there any way to Download a language pack to give offline translation feature

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying to give a feature like google translate app where user can download multiple languages and see translations in those.

More specifically, I need to implement offline language translation. Like a user write some text and wants to translate it in some other language (Spanish or German) without internet.

Is there any way to do that? I'm not able to find anything about this. Please guide me through if someone knows about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not come across any solution that provides this functionality, although as google translate works, you do need to download required language pack one time. Then you can use it offline. Also language packs can be huge so you can definitely not keep all of them saved in your application at once.

In case this is your requirement, you can check out google ML Kit Translator for iOS. This is pretty neat along with the documentation.
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/translation/ios

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've already implemented this into a sample app and tested it. It can help but I'm looking for If I can download a specific language pack and place it in my app and use it locally. 
Please guide me through if you have any idea about it.

Comment: Will update if I find something, although, isn't it the same thing? The user anyways will need to download the pack. The size of the application remains the same, doesn't matter if you download it with the app or after app installation. If you download it after the app launches, there will be a surety that the app always has the latest language pack? The other way, you'll need to make sure that you always keep the latest updated.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.